# Scala FS2 Optimization

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect, fs2

I wrote a little data processing pipeline with FS2 (my first try). It works but is pretty clunky.
The input data are flight records and the output is a Map. A recommendation would be great (Besides creating new data types so that I don't have to sum tuples). Also any recommendations on performance optimization?

This is my code below

```
import cats.effect.{IO, IOApp}
import fs2.{Stream, text}
import fs2.io.file.{Files, Path}
import Utils._
import cats.Semigroup
import cats.syntax.all._
import cats.instances.map._
import cats.instances.vector._
import fs2.Chunk

object FS2Implementation extends IOApp.Simple {

case class SpeedRow(
    recordDate: Date,
    origin: String,
    destination: String,
    distance: Option[Double],
    airtime: Option[Double]
)

  val file = "src/main/FlightData/2018.csv"

  def stringToRows(string: String): SpeedRow = {
    val result = castToSpeedRow(string.split(",").map(_.trim).toVector)
    result
  }

  def getFileStream(path: String): Stream[IO, SpeedRow] =
    val filePath = Path(path)
    Files[IO].readUtf8Lines(filePath).drop(1).dropLast.map(stringToRows)

  def processStream(stream: Stream[IO, SpeedRow]) = {
    def createMapFromRow(
        row: SpeedRow
    ): Map[(String, String), Vector[(Double, Double)]] = Map(
      (row.origin, row.destination) -> Vector(
        (row.airtime.get, row.distance.get)
      )
    )
    val filteredStream =
      stream.filter(p => p.airtime != None && p.distance != None)
    val groupedBy = filteredStream
      .chunkN(10000, true)
      .map(c =>
        c.foldLeft(Map[(String, String), Vector[(Double, Double)]]())(
          (m, row) => m |+| createMapFromRow(row)
        )
      )
    groupedBy
  }

  override def run: IO[Unit] =
    val emptyMap = Map[(String, String), Vector[(Double, Double)]]()
    val vectorOfMaps =
      processStream(getFileStream(file)).compile.toVector
    val elem2 = for
      elem <- vectorOfMaps
      map <- IO(elem.foldLeft(emptyMap)(_ |+| _))
      mapValues <- IO(
        map.mapValues(w =>
          w.foldLeft((0.0, 0.0))((l, r) => (l._1 + r._1, l._2 + r._2))
        )
      )
    yield println(mapValues.toMap.size)
    elem2

}


def castToSpeedRow(row: Vector[String]): SpeedRow =
  val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
  val date = format.parse(row(0))
  val origin = row(3)
  val destination = row(4)
  val airTime = row(20).toDoubleOption
  val distance = row(21).toDoubleOption
  SpeedRow(date, origin, destination, distance, airTime)`
```

Comment: This is a very broad question, so you might not get the answers you are looking for. One thing that might make your code a little less "clunky" could be to to the validation of rows all at once. At some point, you discard all SpeedRows with undefined options. So you might as well define `case class SpeedRow(     ..., distance: Double, airtime: Double)`, change the parsing to `val stringToRows: PartialFunction[String, SpeedRow] = ...` and then replace `.map(stringToRows)` by `.collect(stringToRows)`.

Comment: Also, you could replace `c.foldLeft(Map[(String, String), Vector[(Double, Double)]]())((m, row) => m |+| createMapFromRow(row))` by `c.foldMap(createMapFromRow)`.

Comment: Performancewise, I'd consider to do all folding of Maps on the stream level, i.e. use `foldLeft` on the stream to make it a stream that only emits one map (and not use `.toVector` and then fold the Vector). Or just do `processStream(getFileStream(file)).compile.foldMonoid` to obtain an `IO[Map[(String, String), Vector[(Double, Double)]]]`.

Comment: Another thing: if you `imort cats.Monoid` you could sum your tuples using `Monoid[(Double, Double)].combineAll(w)`

Comment: One more performance consideration: if you really only need the sums that you build in the end, you might want to consider summing up as early as possible (summing as lines get read instead of building up intermediate vectors). That could significantly reduce the overall object allocation count (and garbage collector load).

Comment: This is a case where profiling really matters. Set up a jmh benchmark on the code running over a realistic workload and try different things